# Instrumentation test not creating with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just recently converted my project to Gradle and it works fine.  I'm trying to add some tests to it now.  I followed the Android Gradle user guide for setting up my `build.gradle` with tests.  Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.instrumentTest.java"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/instrumentTest')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I created a package under `src/` called `com.instrumentTest.java` that I put a sample `ServiceTest.java` class in to test my Service.  I run the test using `gradle aDT` and get this:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':<MyProject>:compileDebugAidl'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
<some big command>
Error Code:
        1
Output:
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error don't know what to do with "public"
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error don't know what to do with "public"
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error don't know what to do with "class"
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error don't know what to do with "MyServiceTest"
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error don't know what to do with "extends"
        \src\com\instrumentTest\java\MyServiceTest.java:10: syntax error don't know what to do with "ServiceTestCase<MyService>"
```

It outputs the `syntax error don't know what to do with` for each line of code in my sample test class.  Not really sure what's going on.  The documentation for setting all of this up is pretty fuzzy.

I'm also not really sure the difference between `assembleDebugTest`, `connectedInstrumentTest`, and `installDebugTest` based on their descriptions from running `gradle tasks`.  Is there something I have to do to my manifest in order to have the tests visible to Gradle?  Am I supposed to create my tests in an entirely different project?  I read that previously people would create separate test projects, but since I set the root for instrumentTest in the build.gradle file I assume we can do it all from one project now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In build.gradle, you declared your instrumentTest folder to be in **src/instrumentTest**, which means if you have a test inside that's in the `com.instrumentTest` package, it should be located at **src/instrumentTest/com/instrumentTest/MyServiceTest**. Instead you've put the file at **src/com/instrumentTest/java/MyServiceTest**.

For reasons I don't quite understand it's trying to compile it with the AIDL compiler, and your java file isn't valid AIDL. If you move it to the directory it's expecting for instrumentTest, it should compile okay.

There's an explanation of the Gradle tasks at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks.

- **assembleDebugTest** - The task to assemble the output(s) of the project
- **connectedInstrumentTest** - Runs checks that requires a connected device or emulator. they will run on all connected devices in parallel.
- **installDebugTest** - installs the test APK on the connected device or emulator

Comment: Thanks for your help (and awesome tools!) Scott.  You were right, I messed up the test directory.  The AIDL errors misled me to what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead if you don't want to mess around with the gradle file:
http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/

Basically, you set up and run an Android Test configuration which can run all tests in the module, in a specific package, class or method. So you can set up your test classes wherever you want. It will pick up the test classes without having to modify the build.gradle file and running commands. That also answers your last question, it can be all from one project.

I just started using Android Studio and Gradle and couldn't get the tests to run properly at first until I tried the above. I found it odd having to modify the build.gradle file just to set up a simple test.

Comment: I am using a similar strategy. Did you automate your tests to run on terminal/command line? How did you do?